# how to play alarm to my users every time i insert query in database php

Tags: php, html

i have 2 web pages I have been made with php the first one is for inserting visitors into mysql database the other one is with my manager to let him know which visitor want to met him
my question is how to made the other page play alarm every time i insert someone on my page?

Comment: do you mean alert the user?

Comment: Yes alert him that I inserted new entry into the database

Comment: You can use push notifications for it using node.js. But it is complicated for you

Comment: Example please!!  Or link for it

Answer (score 0):

On manager page put timer which would be running for every 1-2 second, if there is new entry in database, either load all entries or just fetch new entries & append it to existing table.

Comment: How to check from other page that I inserted something new in the database

Comment: Take a timer on your page, on tick event of that timer, you can make a database call & find out new entries.

Comment: int sleep ( int $seconds )

function updateList() {
  retVal = databasecall();
  divGrid.innerHTML =    divGrid.innerHTML + retVal ;
  sleep(2);
}

Answer (score 0):

if somebody wants to meet him, then he's going to need their contact information, right? So send him an email with that information...

```
if($db->query("INSERT INTO users...")) {
    mail($email,$subject,$message);
}
```

otherwise he'll need to keep a browser window open **all the time** to see some kind of alert or refresh.

Comment: Yes he need to keep that window open, that is my understanding.

Comment: Yes he need to keep it open that is why I want this alert to be with sound